# How do I automatically update a task status to 'overdue'?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working at a system in which the user can create tasks, choose their due date, mark them as done and view all tasks in a calendar or in a list. Basically, each task has the `'due_date'`, `'done'` and `'overdue'` fields. I have the following code to check which tasks are overdue:

```
    foreach(Task::all() as $task){
        if($this->due_date->isPast() && !$this->done){
            $task->overdue = 1;
            $task->save();
        }
    }
```

However, I don't know where to place it in order to keep the data up to date without manually copying and pasting it into every function of my controller (which would also make the program extremely slow as data piles up). Any ideas?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you could make a job that does this and have the scheduler schedule it to run when ever you would like ... you can also filter this query more so it only searches for the records with a due_date that has passed and are not marked as done yet and can update them all in one shot

Comment: You can save task information with `over_due` date. then you can create laravel command and run every day and check it is `over_due` then I will update otherwise leave task.

Comment: Or, you could run that code (per logged in user) in the controller that handle index page, before pulling tasks that you send to user index page.